# Visual C++ error LNK1120 compiling

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Good afternoon. I am starting with Visual c++ and I have a compilation problem I dont understand.

The Errors I get are the following :

**error LNK1120 external links unresolved**

**error LNK2019**

I paste the code:

C++TestingConsole.CPP

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "StringUtils.h"
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
using namespace std;
string res = StringUtils::GetProperSalute("Carlos").c_str();
cout << res;
return 0;
}
```

StringUtils.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ostream>
#include "StringUtils.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;


static string GetProperSalute(string name)
{
return "Hello" + name;
}
```

Header: StringUtils.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;



class StringUtils
{

public:

static string GetProperSalute(string name);

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to declare the method `static` in the class definition and qualify it with the class name when you define it:

```
static string GetProperSalute(string name)
{
return "Hello" + name;
}
```

should be

```
string StringUtils::GetProperSalute(string name)
{
return "Hello" + name;
}
```

Other notes:

- remove `using namespace std;`. Prefer full qualifications (e.g. `std::string`)
- your class `StringUtils` seems like it would be better suited as a `namespace` (this will imply more changes to the code)
- `string res = StringUtils::GetProperSalute("Carlos").c_str();` is useless, you can just do: `string res = StringUtils::GetProperSalute("Carlos");`
- pass strings by `const` reference instead of by value: `std::string GetProperSalute(std::string const& name)`

Comment: I have just discovered it, when came to post it Luchian already answered.Thanks dude. PD: Why Is is better to use reference than value? thanks+

Comment: @CarlosLande pass-by-value creates an extra copy. It's better from a performance point of view.